# Gradle delete task failing with "unable to delete file"

Tags: file, gradle, task, delete-file

I have the following delete task added to my build.gradle file:

```
task cleanExtra(type: Delete) {
    delete '../version.properties'
}

clean.dependsOn(cleanExtra)
```

Sometimes, when I call `gradle clean`, it will fail with "Unable to delete file: (...)/version.properties". But if I call the same clean task a second time, it will successfully delete the task.

Why does this happen? Anyway to avoid it?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Yes.

Comment: which version of Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like JIRA issue [Gradle-2244](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2244) :

> Unable to delete file/directory, and then a subsequent clean will
>   succeed.

From the last comment:

> After some research, it appears that this may be due to a bug in the
>   Windows JDKs (incl IBM). Ant uses a strategy of forcing a GC after a
>   failed delete and then waiting a small amount of time. Given that this
>   appears to be a successful strategy for Ant, we have adopted it.

This issue is marked as fixed in version 1.1-rc-1. Presumably the behaviour you observe is "the fix", which a workaround for a JDK bug. So I'd *guess* that this behaviour may occur in later versions of Gradle.

Comment: Does that mean I'll always have to call my clean task twice to make sure the file is deleted?