# Gradle 1.2 - task that works fine on Linux but doesn't work on Windows

Tags: gradle

has anyone any idea why the buildJsbFile task works fine on Linux but buildJsbFileWin doesn't work on Windows? Thanks in advance.

```
task removeJsbFile(type: Delete) {
    delete 'src/main/webapp/app.jsb3'
}

task buildJsbFile(type:Exec, dependsOn: removeJsbFile) {
    workingDir 'src/main/webapp'
    executable 'sencha'
    args 'create jsb -a `http://localhost:8780/login` -p app.jsb3'
}

task buildJsbFileWin(type:Exec, dependsOn: removeJsbFile) {
    workingDir 'src/main/webapp'
    executable 'sencha'
    args 'create jsb -a `http://localhost:8780/login` -p app.jsb3'
}
```

The link is actually without the ` character, I had to use it in order to publish this question

Comment: What error do you see when it doesn't work?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445188/gradle-delete-task-failing-with-unable-to-delete-file

Comment: Is `sencha` a batch script? In any case, the arguments will have to be separated (e.g. by appending `.split()` to the String).

Comment: No error but the file doesnt appear either, that's the strange thing, I also noticed that i use gradle 1.2, not 1.7.

Comment: Its not related to that one, Michael, I mean I expect the file to be created, I don't care much if it is deleted right now...

Comment: Even more strange, if I manually introduce the complete command that should be generated runnning this task, everything works fine.

Comment: Did you try to change `type:Exec` to `ant.exec()`? I had problems using `type:Exec` on some computers. The problem was that the task hangs truing to execute `type:Exec`. The worst was that this occurs only on few computers.

Comment: "Sencha is the file from the Sencha Tools 2.0." That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Also, did you try to separate the arguments as I explained? And what do you mean by "if I manually introduce the complete command that should be generated runnning this task"?

Comment: Sorry Peter, as you probably found out I'm a complete beginner. Only 4 months developing Java, zero days in Gradle. So, yes, the sencha file is in fact a batch script. Could you be more specific with the splitting part please? And if in a command prompt i type $ sencha create jsb -a etc, the complete command... it works fine, the file I'm expecting appears. But my chief wants this to be done automaticaly, in a gradle task, because after generating this file there are some more steps to do. I hope now I wrote it all clear, sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to Peter Niederwieser I managed to solve the problem.

It was all failing because I needed to:

1. split the args String ( 'create jsb -a `http://localhost:8780/login` -p app.jsb3'.split(" ") )
   and
2. change the executable from 'sencha' to 'sencha.bat'

Thank you all guys, especially thank you Peter.